# How to fix ip homestead in homestead.yaml

Tags: networking, vagrant, ip, homestead

I use homestead with hyper-v.
vagrant box run well.

but. IP address has changed, every time.

I fix ip address in Homestead.yaml file. but doesn't work.

I use

- Window 10
- Hyper-v
- vagrant 2.2.6

I try vagrant up 10 times more...

homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: hyperv
```

vagrant up message .

```
PS C:\Users\hi\dev\homestead> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'hyperv' provider...
==> homestead: Verifying Hyper-V is enabled...
==> homestead: Verifying Hyper-V is accessible...
    homestead: Configuring the VM...
==> homestead: Starting the machine...
==> homestead: Waiting for the machine to report its IP address...
    homestead: Timeout: 120 seconds
    homestead: IP: 172.17.76.38
==> homestead: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead: SSH address: 172.17.76.38:22
    homestead: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead: SSH auth method: private key
==> homestead: Machine booted and ready!
```

hyper-v machine ip is 172.17.76.38 ...

How to fix it ???

Answer (score 0):

I recommend switching to VirtualBox or VMware. Your issue is part of limitations of Hyper-V provider as stated on Vagrant's [official website](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/hyperv/limitations.html)